# jQuery: change object's property dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery and I'm working on an app and currently having trouble. I have an object's property that I want to change dynamically on a click event, specially toggling.

example code:

```
var apples = {
value: "$1.00",
propertyIwantToChange: red
};
```

on click event toggle, the property would become green, and click again it would be red.

`propertyIwantToChange: green` --> `propertyIwantToChange: red`--> `propertyIwantToChange: green` and so on.

I was wondering if anyone has any insight for this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Solution from the case as far as you mentioned `apples.propertyIwantToChange = apples.propertyIwantToChange == 'green' ? 'red' : 'green'`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ternary style with a generic function:

```js
var apples = {
  value: "$1.00",
  propertyIwantToChange: 'green'
};

var toggle = function(obj, prop, first, second) {
  obj[prop] = obj[prop] == first ? second : first;
};

$('input').on('click', function() {
  toggle(apples, 'propertyIwantToChange', 'green', 'red');
  console.log(apples.propertyIwantToChange);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Toggle value" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**you can create getter setters for object and then you can check the value and change it accordingly**

```
var apples = {
value: "$1.00",
propertyIwantToChange: 'red',
getpropertyIwantToChange : function(){return this.propertyIwantToChange},
setpropertyIwantToChange : function(val){this.propertyIwantToChange = val}
}
```

**then onclick check the value and set value as you want**

```
    if(apples.getpropertyIwantToChange() == 'red'){
    apples.setpropertyIwantToChange('green')
    }else{
    apples.setpropertyIwantToChange('red')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
    var apples = {
    value: "$1.00",
    propertyIwantToChange: 'red'
  };
   function onClickHndler() {
  // check the property value & change it
  //using ternary operator 
    apples['propertyIwantToChange'] == 'red' ?   
    apples['propertyIwantToChange'] = 'green' : 
    apples['propertyIwantToChange'] = 'red'
}
```

Comment: sorry for typo. Thanks edited it

Answer (score 0):

You mean to use the **ternary operator** here as *@Dhaval Marthak* said,

`apples.propertyIwantToChange = apples.propertyIwantToChange == 'green' ? 'red' : 'green'`

You can read more on **[Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**